# PFUser registration error when using Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I used Parse lots of times before. We have a complicated relation with it. Now I'm in the hate phase of our relation. Just downloaded the latest `SDK`, linked it with my project and put the `sample code` to test if the integration works. It didn't. Here's what I did: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/swift/existing

I did nothing other than copying and pasting the `sample code` into my project. This is the error I get, I know many of you already know this error:
PFUser must be registered with registerSubclass before using Parse

Note that I didn't subclass PFUser yet.

Comment: Never heard of that error message. Your message is literally "PFUser registration error"? Or "PFUser registration error when using Swift"? Or what? Neither gives results on google either...

Comment: Sorry, I changed the title after I've written the post. Fixing the text now. The error is: PFUser must be registered with registerSubclass before using Parse